# VSCode open-in-browser won't open google-chrome (ubuntu)

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code

When I try to run the open-in-browser extension (TechER version; there are a few such extensions by roughly the same name) in VS Code (1.41.1), I continually get the following error message: "Open browser failed!! Please check if you have installed the browser correctly!"
I reinstalled google-chrome, made sure it was default, double-checked the xdg settings, but it still won't work.  Any suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is no binary executable named `google-chrome` may be yours is google-chrome-stable .

One thing you can do is to copy the binary file `google-chrome-stable` and create a renamed file google-chrome

Or you can set a bah alias

`alias google-chrome='google-chrome-stable'`

Comment: Thanks. The alias trick had no effect. both "google-chrome" and "google-chrome-stable" will open a browser from a shell.  I'm not sure if that means an alias of some sort already existed.  xdg-settings get default-web-browser returns "google-chrome.desktop".  Also, if I try right-clicking on a file, i get a list of installed browsers (chrome, firefox, and opera).  Each yields same message "Open browser failed!! Please check if you have installed correctly."  For chrome and opera, they fail silently and just show that message; Firefox shows "We're sorry.  Firefox had a problem and crashed"

Comment: Why dont you create your own shortcut key or somethimg with a custom command to open the current file or run the cirrent project on  a browser of your choice instead of relying on a plugin it shouldn't be that hard

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue with the "open in browser" extension. I clicked on the settings icon and installed an older version 1.1.0. Its working again for me.